# how to minimise a long && statement - Java

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to check if all of the items in array `squareData[]` is 5.

I could just do this:

`if(squareData[0] == 5 && squareData[1] == 5 && ...){...}`

But it seems rather inefficient.

Is there a way to minimise this into a `for` loop of some kind?

Note that the size of `squareData[]` is 9 items

Thanks!

Comment: `Is there a way to minimise this into a for loop of some kind?` Yes.

Comment: "But it seems rather inefficient" - do you mean you don't like the look of the source code, or that you think it will take a long time to execute?

Comment: Simply create a helper function to do just that for you? e.g. `private boolean areAllEqual(int[] squareData, int value) { for (int i : squareData) { if (i != value) { return false; } } return true; }` Then use like `areAllEqual(squareData, 5)`

Comment: @nbokmans Ugh can you please not put code in the comments?

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino this question shouldn't really be answered and will probably be closed due to low quality/some duplicate, so I didn't want to karma farm and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your input in an `int[]`, you can use `Stream`s:

```
if (Arrays.stream(squareData).allMatch(i -> i==5)) {

}
```

This will return true if all the elements in your array satisfy the condition `i==5`.

Comment: The guy doesn't even know how to iterate over an array, how can you suggest streams and lambdas. I mean, your answer is very correct, it's actually the best one, but you know...he ain't gonna learn what he wanted to know...

Comment: @payloc Well, if the OP is interested in learning, they can learn different ways to achieve their goal by reading the different answers here.

Answer (score 1):

Convert to stream and use allMatch method:

```
java.util.stream.Stream.of(squareData).allMatch(v -> v == 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to [java](/questions/tagged/java).

Regardless of the array size, the most basic way is

```
boolean allEqual = true;

for (long l : squareData) {
    if (l != 5) {
        allEqual = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Once you dive deeper into the language, you will find new methods to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean haveAllItemsCorrectValue(int[] array) {
    for (int value : array) {
        if (value != 5) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

And then

```
if(haveAllItemsCorrectValue(squareData){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something like:

```
boolean isOk = true;
for(int i=0; i<squareData.length; i++)
    if(squareData[i]!=5)
       isOk=false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean allFive = true;
for ( int i = 0; i < squareData.length; ++i ) {
  if ( 5 != squareData[i] ) {
    allFive = false;
    break;
  }
}
System.out.println(
  allFive ? "All entries are five." : "At least one entry is not five."
);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.